# appending elements to dictionary in python

Tags: python

```
dictionary = {}

tabl = [('maint_id', 1003L), ('type', 'DB'), ('number', '102')]
for i in tabl:
     dictionary{i[0]:i[1]}


print dictionary
```

It is giving me only the last key value pair in my dictionary. it is overwritting all the elements.  what is wrong with this code.. any help

Comment: Actually, that isn't valid Python. Did you mean `dictionary = {i[0]:i[1]}`?

Answer (score 6):

It's much easier:

```
dictionary = dict(tabl)
```

If order matters:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dictionary = OrderedDict(tabl)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
for i in tabl:
     dictionary[i[0]] = i[1]
```

Comment: but there is one problem, the order got changed. i need it in the same order which the data entering      In [13]: for i in tabl:
   ....:     dictionary[i[0]] = i[1]
   ....:     
   ....:     

In [14]: dic
dict        dictionary  

In [14]: dictionary
Out[14]: {'number': '102', 'maint_id': 1003L, 'type': 'DB'}

Comment: @just_in Dictionaries have no order. You need to use [``OrderedDict``](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for that.